# Add multiple ActionName for button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one controller on which i have Save button click event. Im using same controller and view for Add and Edit purpose. My code is as per below

```
[HttpPost]
            [Button(ButtonName = "Save")]
            [ActionName("Create")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "PostData")]
            public ActionResult Save(Ntegra m_Ntegra,FormCollection form)
            {}
```

As Im Using ActionName("Create") here so button can not work for ActionName("Edit"). can anyone tell me how i can achive my requirnment!!
Thanks for help...... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one view i.e `Edit or Create` but you would need to write 2 different Controllor actions (Create,Edit).

Please refer [`MVC Music store CodePlex project`](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) which will give you idea on what conventions are used and to write standard MVC code

Answer (score 0):

You can have action method named Save and pass the Model. IN action method you can check if ID is exist in model or not. If there is pre defined ID you can update the record otherwise you can create new record. IN you For FormCollection, while rendering the form use hidden field to store the Id field.

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
            {}
```

Comment: I have some more buttons on my view

Comment: I hope only Save button will do the post (and action is also configured in form tag where data will post). Other button simply do the redirection through link; like if you have cancel button, change it to anchor tag and url must go to some other page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really required two controller actions for `create` and `edit`, you can have a single action  without decorating with `ActionName` attribute.

In the single controller action you have to check the `id` of the entity going to be saved, if there is some value then it will be edit else create.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Ntegra m_Ntegra)
{
  if(m_Ntegra.Id == 0)
  {
    // create
  }
  else
  {
    // edit
  }
}
```

Comment: But i have Save,Cancel,Ping these three buttons on my view eberytime it post back will get confused abt action